# I want to run func zure functionnapp publish on mac m1

Tags: azure-functions

I've typed `func azure functionapp publish xxxxx`, but it just displays something like help, and no more action.

[image]

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: What is that `xxxx` in the command - Is it your function app name?

Comment: Have you created the function app resource in Azure Cloud, then `xxxx` should be that function app to which your local function project will be deployed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to publish the Azure Functions Project with Functions core tools command, check the arguments passing in the command if anything is incorrect.
Reference of Command: [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish) of Functions Core Tools Publish

When you deploy for the 1st time, it shows the Storage account connection string and pre-deployment result:

[image]

If the profile exists for deployment of Functions project, then below is the output of publishing the functions using Core tools cmdlets:

```
 C:\Users\HariKR\source\repos\Python\KrishPyFunApp01> func azure functionapp publish Harispyfunapp
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 7.31 MB [###############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id 'e8138f96-3'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.10.4 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20220815.2, Commit: <Alpha_Num>, ReleaseTagName: 20220815.2

Build Operation ID: <Alpha_NumericId>
Repository Commit : <Alpha_Numeric_Guid_Id>

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.10.4


Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot

Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.10.4/bin/python3.10
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...
Done in 1 sec(s).
[10:25:03+0000] Collecting azure-functions
[10:25:03+0000]   Using cached azure_functions-1.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
[10:25:03+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions
[10:25:04+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.13.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.10.4/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 1 sec(s).
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
Inode table size 18330 bytes (17.90 Kbytes)
        28.96% of uncompressed inode table size (63296 bytes)
Directory table size 18143 bytes (17.72 Kbytes)
        35.20% of uncompressed directory table size (51549 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 155
Number of inodes 1972
Number of files 1763
Number of fragments 141
Number of symbolic links  0
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 209
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
Number of uids 1
        root (0)
Number of gids 1
        root (0)
Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-HarisPyFunApp.zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for harispyfunapp.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
Syncing triggers...
Functions in HarisPyFunApp:
    HttpTrigger1 - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://harispyfunapp.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1
```

[image]

[image]